# How to keep insulated water pipes in attached garage and attic in garage from freezing again

Tags: water

My water pipes, insulated, are in my garage and garage attic. It is a 2 car garage attached to my home. The pipes froze and I had no water for a week. I bought a 1500w space heater that is not doing much of anything.I am also worried about power going off. Would insulated garage doors help and be worth the money? I have some gas in the house. What about a gas heater?Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: How are the pipes insulated?  Are they inside a wall on the heated side with the insulation on the cold side?  Is the garage insulated?  Insulated doors not much use unless the garage is also.

Comment: If there are drafts blowing on the pipes then insulate the pipes. If the pipes are in frequent use then that may be sufficient.

Comment: at bare minimum install a temperature monitor on the water pipe. At least you will be alerted if the pipe temperature drops below freezing and you can take action.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that proper re-plumbing through conditioned spaces is not an option then you could buy an automatic electric heat cable.

I read the product specs on this 30' Frost King brand and it uses 7 watts per foot so a 15 amp circuit could safely support up to 205 feet of continuous operation.

[image]

Just make sure to read all safety precautions especially in regards to using it in conjunction with insulation and pipe material.

Comment: You can also get product like this that is a wrap and automatically controls how much current flows inversely with temperature so you can always keep it plugged in or hardwire it.

Comment: @GlenYates Yep, lots of choices out there. None of which are 100% guaranteed to work for OP since we don't know their skill level nor utility configuration.

Comment: how is this going to work over the existing insulation ?

Comment: Do have to be careful if the pipes are a plastic type and insulated or will have insulation placed on them.